# Default layout of login.phtml

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1, template, layout, login

How can i change the default layout of login.phtml in magento. Suppose , now by default the layout for login.phtml is **1column.phtml** and if I want this to **change** to **3column.phtml**, what should I do?

Comment: You seem to have a number of questions and no accepted answers on any of them. Before asking more questions on this forum I suggest you look through your past questions and accept some answers. Thanks.

Comment: @philwinkle. By "a number of questions" you mean "all", right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just extending the answer given by philwinkle.

If you are doing any layout updates then it is recommended to do it in a separate file normally with a name of "*local.xml*". If this file is not available in "*$theme/$layout/*" folder then **create one** and add the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<layout>
    <customer_account_login>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>page/3column.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </customer_account_login>
</layout>
```

Updates to layout are processed in a single file. you can also do the updates in many files but it will end in confusion. and also if you are upgrading your magento package then those update changes will be lost.

Hence, keeping updates in a single file makes sense.

It seems you are beginner in magento. So, I would like to recommend you few links from where you can understand it better. :)

- 1) http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/demystifying-magentos-layout-xml-part-1/
- 2) http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/digging-deeper-into-magentos-layout-xml-part-2/
- 3) http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/creating-custom-layout-handles/

Well, I am also a beginner but learnt alot from the above links :)

Comment: Okay thanks, but I created a new local.xml file and pasted the above code , but I am not getting the output.

Comment: It should work. you can see that change when "customer_account_login" layout handle is called. Go through those tutorials.

Comment: @AkashGoswami I updated my post check once and let me know.

Comment: the code which you provided initially that worked for me and I have also specified that in a local.xml.

Comment: @AkashGoswami then please select the answer which helped you. otherwise we can't help you in future. because this site needs some accepted answers to survive.

Comment: Okay , since I am new to stackExchange can you let me know how do I accept a particular answer?

Comment: @AkashGoswami please read this [post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/196352).

Answer (score 6):

Insert the following into your theme's `local.xml` layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <customer_account_login>
          <reference name="root">
                <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/3column.phtml</template></action>
          </reference>
    </customer_account_login>
</layout>
```

Comment: Okay but can you please tell me where is that local.xml located?

Comment: app/design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/layout/local.xml

Comment: Package is what package you've defined in your System > Config > Design for your store view. Theme is what is listed for Theme in that same configuration panel.

Comment: Thank you. It worked. Actually I changed the layout directly from customer.xml file.

Comment: Great to hear - please upvote and accept this answer. I would encourage you to not make the change in the customer.xml if your theme is base/default as this will be overwritten during an upgrade. Best of luck.

Comment: @AkashGoswami don't do that. It will work but not recommended. if there is not `local.xml` file, then create one and do as suggested by philwinkle.

Comment: Yes, I created a new and pasted the above code given by you, but I could not get any output. It seems that it is overriding  the code written in customer.xml. Can I ask what may be the consequences in editing that piece of code in customer.xml file?

Comment: The consequences are that if you ever upgrade this change will be lost. If it works for you in customer.xml then no harm done. Please accept this answer if it solved the question for you.

Comment: It is best practice to use a local.xml file whenever possible.
This has some advantages. The local.xml is always processed last. Therefore it overrides all other .xml files in the layout folder. Furthermore it keeps every change at one point which makes it easy to search for layout changes.
And if a magento .xml file gets updated you won't have to include your changes in that file again.
You will still automatically benefit from changes in the magento core .xml files.

Answer (score 3):

```
<layout>
      <customer_account_login>
           <reference name="root">
                <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/3column.phtml</template></action>
            </reference>
         </customer_account_login>
</layout>
```

write this code in `local.xml` in your theme layout

Comment: It will not work because the layout handle "customer_account_login" is not present inside the "default" layout handle. or if you are including in "default" layout handle then you need to use `update` layout element. correct me if I am wrong. :)

Comment: you are right @Mr_Green updated my answer